# How to add security zone information to files?

Tags: windows, security, attachments

I recently enabled "Do not preserve zone information in file attachments", to get rid that annoying "Do you want to run this program" security warning.  Now, how can I add this information to a file that doesn't have it?  I would like to get that warning back on certain files when I try to run them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the elevated command-line (administrator rights) do this:

```
icacls <filename> /setintegritylevel low
```

This achieves what you have asked for.